# How can I print the folder name without the need for a function?

Tags: python

How can I print the folder name without the need for a function?

```
def start_capture():
     
    name = Entry(root, width=50, font=('Helvetica', 24))
    name.pack()
    name.insert(0, "Enter Folder Name: ")
    name.delete(0, 'end')
print(name)
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. I can only guess you use some kind of gui framework, possibly `Tk`. Would you mind adding some details? Also your question isn't clear. You need to be more specific what you want to acheive.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tkinter, then use the .get() method.

```
print(name.get())
```